# Global scaffold to show Snackbar in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to structure a flutter app with a single global scaffold to show and interact with a snackbar over every widgets.

My current solution is to have a nested material app with the top one as a host to a scaffold with a global scaffold key. Which is probably not a good practice.

Here is the current code:

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        body: MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyApp',
          builder: (context, navigator) {
            return navigator
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Is there any other solution without having to resort to nested material app? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If your root widget contains a scaffold then all the child widgets can show a snackbar using.

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Comment: I believe this is only true if there is 1 scaffold. But if you are 4 pages in, the snackbar will not be shown in the outermost scaffold

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MaterialApp builder to "automatically" wrap all your routes in a Scaffold like this.

```
 MaterialApp(
            title: 'MyApp',
            builder: (context, child) =>
                Scaffold(appBar: null, body: child));
```

Then you can normally use `Scaffold.of(context)` or a global `scaffoldKey`